# Unable to establish link between Firefox and Selenium Web driver with multiple versions

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Used the below Configuration:

Firefox: Version 46.0.1
Selenium Web Driver:2.53.1
OS:Windows 10 64 Bit

**Alternatively tried**:

Firefox: Version 26.0
Selenium Web Driver:2.40.0
OS:Windows 10 Bit[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc53I.png)

**Facing the below issue consistently**:

1)Getting below error:

"Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.
Although I believe its right and most suggested compatible pair of Firefox and Selenium Web Driver.Kindly help me suggest a solution or the best compatible version.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try FF 47.0.1 with selenium 2.53.1. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am using selenium 2.53.0 with with firefox version 43.0.1. You may try this combination. I think, this might help although there are several combinations too.

Comment: Can you please provide me all several combinations to help with

Comment: You may try with those pair first. Hope, it will help.

Comment: No luck!!! its opening FF driver but not pasting the url  of the application and  same error again